Flutter. Android. Open app from notification on lock screen
On the native app, I have set android:showWhenLocked=“true” in AndroidManifest. This allows me to show full screen intent on the lock screen. At the same time, tapping another notification on the lock screen requires unlocking the phone before opening the app. This works as expected.
On flutter, I am using the flutter_local_notifications library. I also set android:showWhenLocked=“true” in androidManifest. But when I tap on some notification on the lock screen, the behavior is different from native. The request to unlock the phone appears for a second, but the app opens immediately without entering a password. If I set showWhenLocked to false, unlocking the phone becomes necessary, but the full-screen intent on the lock screen no longer works.
What can I do in this situation? How can I combine the full screen intent on the lock screen and the request to unlock the phone before opening an app from a notification on the lock screen?

Hey can we talk on this, its sound interesting,

sure, any ideas?
